# PHP parse empty data from csv file

Tags: php

I'm trying to get data from a csv file line by line using PHP, and then insert into Mysql.

Some of the values in the rows of the csv file are empty, and need to be loaded as Null values into Mysql. I can't seems to check these values though. I've tried:

```
        if (strlen($csv[9])==0) {
            $follow_up1 = null;
        } else {
            $follow_up1 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($csv[9]);
        }
```

or:

```
    if (empty($csv[9]) {
        $follow_up1 = null;
    } else {
        $follow_up1 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($csv[9]);
    }
```

or:

```
    if (is_null($csv[9]) {
        $follow_up1 = null;
    } else {
        $follow_up1 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($csv[9]);
    }
```

How can I check if the cell value is empty?

Comment: How do you parse your data? What exactly marks it as "empty"?

Comment: Can you show the content of `$csv` ?

Comment: Please show us a `var_dump($csv)`

Comment: It seems you are concatenating an sql query from your variable names. Setting a variable to `null` will then not write a null value to the database, as you would need to put the string `NULL` without quotes into the query. Instead you should use prepared statements, then you can pass null values, and also get rid of the `real_escape_string`, and be save(r) against sql injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a string to place into an insert query, that can be the string NULL, then you need to add the single quotes at the same time:

```
if (empty($csv[9]) {
    $follow_up1 = "NULL"; // a string between quotes
} else {
    $follow_up1 = "'" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($csv[9]) . "'";
}
```

And then use `$follow_up1` in the SQL without quotes

Comment: this is correctly inserting empty values as NULL, but valid values ('else') as number `0`... any ideas?

Comment: ah i made it wrong. too much java coding .. Need to concatenate string with a dot.

Answer (score 1):

at the second  example you are missing a ")" so this might throw you an error.

```
if (empty($csv[9])) {
        $follow_up1 = null;
    } else {
        $follow_up1 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($csv[9]);
    }
```

you could also search :

```
$follow_up1 = $csv[9] === '' ? null : $mysqli->real_escape_string($csv[9]);
```

or :

```
 $follow_up1 = $csv[9] === "NULL" ? null : $mysqli->real_escape_string($csv[9]);
```

that if what you have there is an empty string .

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
if (trim($csv[9]) === '') {
    $follow_up1 = null;
} else {
    $follow_up1 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($csv[9]);
}
```